# powershell batch rename files maintain only five numbers and add a prefix

Tags: powershell, rename

I want to rename multiple files JPG in a folder but the only thing that I want to maintain is  five numbers and add a prefix "nu"
example:

```
206_00013.jpg -> nu00013.jgp
339-67003-primeur.jpg -> nu67003.jpg 
16126._1.jpg -> nu16126.jpg
```

The problem is that the original files they don't have "logic"

Can anyone please point me in the right direction here? I'm not very familiar with Powershell at all.
Thanks

Comment: You say the files *don't have "logic"*.  I assume you mean that there aren't necessarily simple patterns in the filenames.  Do they all at least have the 5 number group, and only one such group?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '.*(\d{5}).*', '$1') + $_.Extension }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the base name contains a string of 5 digits, if so rename:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg |ForEach-Object{
    if($_.BaseName -match '\d{5}'){
        Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "nu$($Matches[0]).jpg"
    } else {
        Write-Warning "5 digits not found in filename $($_.Name)"
    }
}
```